# Exploratory factor analysis of a non-normally distributed data set with probable multicollinearity problems

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis, multicollinearity, nonlinear

I am trying to develop a scale measuring employee satisfaction regarding organizational support using spss. Most of my variables are positively skewed which should not be a problem in EFA as long as PAF is used for extraction . When examining the factorability of the data, kmo and Bartlettas are OK, however, the determinant is much lower than the .00001cutoff, indicating severe multicollinearity. Is VIF still the appropriate collinearity diagnostics indicator? Or should I transform all the variables first which is not recommended generally? Thank you.

Best,
 Chiman

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why do you think transforming variables would get rid of collinearity? Also, where does the notion of a cutoff value for the determinant come from?

Comment: I am thinking of transforming them not to get rid of collinearity, but to enable the use of vif as the indicator which I am uncertain if normality is assumed. Sorry for my misleading wordings, greater than the value .00001is a rule of thumb, it is not a definite cutoff, but mine is some 2.4e-8 which is definitely too small

Comment: In reverse, are all those indicators suggesting factorability applicable to skewed data?

Comment: One seldom hears of VIF being used in the course of scale development. 
 Often people developing such scales are trying to balance the trade-off between coverage of the domain (content validity), which favors relatively low item correlations, and homogeneity (internal consistency reliability), which favors high item correlations.  How would you describe your priorities?